# answering command automatically - performing cp operation between answers

Tags: bash, shell, cp, cat, expect

The idea is that I want to execute a command, then it asks for a file name to process, and after it is done with processing, it outputs an image with the name `prediction.png`, it asks for the next filename and so on.
I have thousands of files, so I cannot enter them manually one by one. However, I have a .txt file containing all the filenames.

So I wanted to write a bash script which:

1- execute the command

2- when it asks about a filename, it reads the first line from the txt file

3- the program will process the file, outputs an image, then cp this image to another directory (to avoid overwriting for the next file)

4- then asks for the next, do the same and so on

until the program asks for a file, and already the .txt file is done, then it terminates automatically

What I can do up till now is reading files one by one and passing them as answers for my program when it asks using

```
cat filenames.txt | ./program.sh
```

The problem, is that I want to `cp` the output before processing the new file

Comment: crossposted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060761/automatically-answer-input-in-command-line

Comment: it is a new question to the same script.

Comment: @steeldriver yes different question but related to the same script

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify `program.sh`?

Comment: @glennjackman it is an exe dependent on some c files, so it is too much, because I need to edit the c files and then make again and so
that's why I was looking for an easier solution

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this while running `program.sh` just once, as it will continue creating the files, and you can never be sure when a file is complete.

Instead run the program once for each line filenames.txt:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r FILE; do # loop through files in filenames.txt
  echo "$FILE" | ./program.sh # run program once and end it with newline
  mv created_filename /some/other/location/${FILE}.ext; # move file
done < filenames.txt
```

- Use `mv` instead of `cp`, it will be faster if you're moving to the same file system.
- Change `.ext` to the output format (e.g. `.png`).

Comment: The problem that running the program takes time, but it is already supporting the option of passing multiple files. That's why it is much much faster to run it once, then whenever it asks for a file, I pass its name to it

Comment: If you have access to the original script, edit it, but without being able to change it, I think you have no choice.

Comment: concerning the part where you said 'I will never be sure when a file is complete', no I will, because when it is done with a file, it asks for a new file, and accordingly, I can pass the new file name

Comment: someone familiar with `expect` may help you ...

Comment: The counter, `n`, is never incremented.

Comment: `echo -e "$FILE\n"` is too much work: what's wrong with plain `echo "$FILE"` ? If you want that much control over the newlines in the output, use `printf "%s\n" "$FILE"`

Comment: @glennjackman anyways, all of these suggestions won't perform what I really want

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
(
while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    echo "$FILE"
    sleep 1 # or somehow make a trigger to see when the file is ready ...
    mv output_file /somewhere/else
done < filenames.txt;
) | ./program.sh
```

([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616027/how-to-send-to-stdin-in-bash-10-seconds-after-starting-the-process))

---

same using xargs:

```
(
xargs -a filenames.txt -I{} sh -c 'echo {}; sleep 1; mv file /somewhere/else'
) | ./program.sh
```

Comment: Please tell me what is wrong when downvoting, so I can learn.